# Counting ICD-10 codes in a column

Tags: count

I am working with ICD-10 codes and want to summarize how many, for instance, start with "O" in a specific column of my table. I am looking for some syntax to isolate the column and perform this count. Thanks for the help!

I tried using "counter" and it does not seem to work the way I want it to

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.